# How to update data into database using DataSet without OracleDataAdapter ADO.NET

Tags: c#, database, oracle, ado.net, dataset

I have to write method Commit(DataSet) that should update data in the database using only this DataSet, without OracleDataAdapter. 
How can I do this?

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this example https://github.com/nreco/data/tree/master/examples/DataSetGenericDataAdapter that implements 'generic' database-independent `DbDataAdapter` that can be used for DataSet update and Oracle ADO.NET provider.